# Usage of as keyword in typescript

Tags: typescript, tsc, react-native-paper

In an object the developer defined code constants like this:

```
medium: {
      fontFamily: 'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
      fontWeight: '500' as '500',
    },
```

What is the as keyword doing?

Comment: as keyword is used for type casting in typescript. But here I find no use case of as keyword in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `as '500'` is doing in this case is setting up the fontWeight to be unable to be changed by making the fontWeight property of type `'500'` rather than type `string` which it would be without that line.

For example, in this [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIHUQCcDWMC8MDeAoGMAZuFAGICGAtgJYA2AngFwwDkASiAEYhQgA0MAEQAJAKa0AbqKjVg5GADlRAV1GCBYydNnkBAQWTVytARHKQAtBFGHCLPviIkEo6gHMAFlGYsArAAZ-FhhyCFYAoIcAX1x4JDQAOmIwKBd3Lww-AE4s4IB6PJgAFXoAB1FWQV8cwWDqMPhYUIh3MHJOWgreGCgyipYqwNqE3FxQSFgAdxRUMKw8AmSyKjomVg5uXgERcSkZOUUVNQ1d7Tl9Q2NTcwgrG2o7B0XnV09vcMD7XBjptAgkl7pKCZaq5UbjaAwSgoUQAeVKMnAcxwjiWFBoDB8Gx4-CEmj2OkOqnUMHxZ10MAMRhMMDMlmsti+zxSaTePgiwVCHyCAB8WAA2T58gDsn2iuGhyDhCOoSIBLNeGQFnwlMPhiMg8tSiuBLAALAAmXz5QolcqVQ2+WowepwHghCAtNxtDpdEA9PqVCKCGA8oSC-w+v2CUWBlgJIA) link, you'll notice that `noWork` has a type error when assigning a new value to fontWeight, while `works` allows it.

I've also added an example `moreOptions` with a string literal type union. As fontWeights generally only work with specific values, it's a great case for a union that will prevent invalid values from being assigned.

```
const noWork = {
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
  fontWeight: '500' as '500',
}
noWork.fontWeight='599' // Type '"599"' is not assignable to type '"500"'.

const works = {
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
  fontWeight: '500',
}
works.fontWeight='599'

const moreOptions = {
  fontFamily: 'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
  fontWeight: '500' as '500'|'600'|'700',
}
moreOptions.fontWeight='600'
moreOptions.fontWeight='425' // Type '"425"' is not assignable to type '"500" | "600" | "700"'.
```

Limiting the types that are allowed for a variable is a very helpful part of typescript especially when there are certain values that work for a property.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `as` does nothing.

```js
const x = '500';
const y = '500' as '500';
const z = '500' as string;

console.log(x === y);
console.log(z === y);
console.log(x === z);
```

Will output

```js
true
true
true
```

A note I should add - TypeScript has something called [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) which allow you to define the set of strings a variable is allowed to take. However, using them in this case is pointless because `'500'` is obviously already of type `'500'`.